# http-backend-proxy is not working with protractor e2e

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm new to e2e testing and angular, and am trying to figure out how to mock http requests. I have an app that I need to make xhr requests to things like a footer and a constants file, that I want to actually go through, but the actual service calls like adding something to the DB, I want to mock (so that whenever I run e2e tests it doesn't populate test data everytime).

I will eventually be hitting an API, but just to get the ball rolling I am making an $http get to `/someUrl` on that function which handles that element's click.

```
describe('companyManagement', function() {
    var proxy;
    var HttpBackend = require('http-backend-proxy');
    beforeEach(function(){
        proxy = new HttpBackend(browser);

        proxy.onLoad.whenGET('/someUrl/').respond(200,{'mock':'data'});
        browser.get('/#/companyManagement');

        browser.pause();
        element(by.repeater('org in vm.organizations').row(0)).element(by.css('.contentHeader')).click();
    });
    it('alias should be correct in the org list', function(){
        var x;
    });
});
```

This is my current code. I require http-backend-proxy, and set some things up in my before each for my it statements that I will write later on. The beforeEach creates a new HttpBackend object, and does `proxy.onLoad.whenGET('/someUrl').respond(200,{mock:'data'});`. I then get the page (a baseUrl is set in my .conf file), and pause the browser so I can view the console. At this point, when I view the browser console, it gives my Unexpected Request errors. One for `modules/footer/footer.html` and one for `constants/constants.json`.

> Error: Unexpected request: GET modules/footer/footer.html
>   No more request expected
>   $httpBackend@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1244:1
>   sendReq@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10515:1
>   $http/serverRequest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10222:16
>   processQueue@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14745:28
>   scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14761:27
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15989:16
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15800:15
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16097:13
>   bootstrapApply@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1660:9
>   invoke@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4478:14
>   bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1658:1
>   bootstrap/angular.resumeBootstrap@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1686:12
>   anonymous@http://localhost:9000/#/companyManagement line 69 > Function:1:1
>   handleEvaluateEvent@http://localhost:9000/#/companyManagement:69:20

Nothing is displayed on the page, so protactor cannot click that element. I've tried things like `proxy.onLoad.whenGET('/.*/').respond(200,{'mock':'data'});`, but the same error occurs.

Can someone explain to me how to properly mock up http requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make all requests for HTML and other static files to pass through using respective method. *http-backend-proxy* will just ignore them and their response will be untouched.

```
proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();
proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/constants\.json$/).passThrough();
```

It' a common approach, because SPA usually make a lot of XHR requests to fetch templates, which don't have to be mocked in most of the cases. But because *http-backend* tracks all requests by default, you have to explicitly tell which particular ones need to be ignored.

Comment: I'll try this out on Monday and get back to you, thanks for answering

Comment: thank you. I think part of the reason why it wasn't working for me is that I included 'ngMockE2E' as a dependency in app.js and it was breaking everything.